# mysql_tzinfo_to_sql ORDER BY Error

Tags: mysql, sql, tzinfo

I need to run the utility `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` for a project and whenever I try to run the first command :

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1105 (HY000) at line 46426: ORDER BY ignored as there is a user-defined clustered index in the table 'time_zone_transition'
```

My understanding is because the `ORDER BY` is not processed it won't go any further in updating the timezones, though I have never touch this base, I am not sure how can I best solve this issue.

Also when trying to run:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql tz_file tz_name | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

I get the following error:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql: Can't create/write to file 'tz_file' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
Problems with zoneinfo file 'tz_file'
```

**EDIT:** I am running on a macOS Sierra (10.12.6)
And I was trying to do all that because of that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/#mysql-time-zone-definitions

Comment: Not an answer, but you should tell us whether you are running Windows or Linux.  Configuring timezone tables is slightly different on each type of OS.

Comment: Good point, just updated the comment!

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer which I think should be safe and should get around the error you are having.  From the documentation, I believe the table `time_zone_transition` should be empty by default.  So, I think you can try truncating this table and then removing all indices:

```
DELETE FROM time_zone_transition
```

It sounds like somehow there are one or more indices on this table which are causing problems.  I recommend just removing all indices:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM time_zone_transition
```

Then do the following for each index:

```
ALTER TABLE time_zone_transition DROP INDEX some_index
```

Finally, try running your initial command again:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

If this still fails, with the same error, then the error we are trying to fix is not the root cause of the problem.  Then, we would have more work to do here.

Comment: The INDEX here is the primary key, it looks like the following:
```PRIMARY KEY (`Time_zone_id`,`Transition_time`)``` thus I am wondering if deleting it is a good idea ?